# What is the difference between static reference variable and instance reference variable in initiating?

Tags: java

I'm confused about an essential thing in java.

```
public class InitItself1 {

    public InitItself1(){}

    private InitItself1 me = new InitItself1();
}
```

Of course I know that the StackOverFlowError will be occurred when creating an instance of the above class. The above class will be initiated recursively itself because of the initiation of the variable "me".

But,

```
public class InitItself2 {

    public InitItself2(){}

    private static InitItself2 me = new InitItself2();
}
```

Of course the outcome of the above class, "InitItself2" is different to the prior class, "InitItself1". This works just fine, no error occurred. As I know, initiating static variables and executing static blocks are performed when classes in which static variables and blocks are loaded.

What makes me confused is that I think it's the same that the variables, "me" of both classes, "InitItself1" and "InitItself2" are initiated, and also they have references to their classes in which they are, so it looks that "initiating recursively" would happen in initiating both classes.

What is the point that I'm missing? 
Good answer please. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Are you confused about the fact that static variables are only initialized once per class, instead of per instance?

Comment: Kayaman, not that. I'm confused about how the initiating static variables is performed.

Comment: In the regular way, when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not going to get StackOverFlowError in the second case. As you have said yourself, static variables are initiated when the class is loaded, and because a class is only loaded once, the static `InitItself2 me` will only be instantiated once. Creating a new object with constructor doesn't require the class to be reloaded.

```
public final class InitItself {

    static {
        System.out.println("Class is loaded");
    }

    private static InitItself me = new InitItself();

    static {
        System.out.println("me is instantiated");
    }

    public InitItself() {
        System.out.println("Constructor called, me=" + me);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("START");
        InitItself i = new InitItself();
        System.out.println("FINISH");
    }
}
```

Gives the following output

```
Class is loaded
Constructor called, me=null
me is instantiated
START
Constructor called, me=oop.InitItself@6ff3c5b5
FINISH
```

Comment: NOTE: If you create an instance while initialising the class, it is possible to read a `static final` variable before it has been initialised (if initialisation hasn't completed yet) +1

Comment: I suggest adding to the example what happens if you print `me` in the constructor as you will get different results in each case.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yep, good suggestions ;) I'll add it to the example.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I was missing the fact that initiating static variables is performed once. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You could also note that the thread initialising the class holds an implicit lock so no other thread can access it while it's being initialised.

Comment: really?? I'm reading Java Concurrency in Practice. but as I remember that "must be careful when initiating instances in multi thread programming", because it can happen that one thread may access a class when initializing the class's instance. It is different? Aha, I think your meaning, "initializing" is not "executing constructor". OK. I think I got it. haha